# Is there any possibility of a man in the middle attack?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

Sorry if my question sounds dumb, maybe it is, I am worried about a detail that I have noticed.
If I was more expert about the topic I am going to ask you about I would certainly not ask about it, so please give me a useful answer.

My Terminal prompt now is the following:

```
Last login: Sat Oct 21 23:04:09 on ttys005
dhcp-MyIpAddress:~ MyUsername$
```

I have never had the string "dhcp" before my username, I had something like MyUsername's-MacBook-Pro, but not my IP address.

Can someone explain me a possible cause of why all of the sudden it has changed?

I am asking this question because I have noticed that when I use a VPN that string changes, but now I am not using anything similar, is it possible that I am under a man in the middle attack?

EDIT:
apparently I am not the only who has this question: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1827982?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to believe you are based on the information you've given. The text at the beginning of your prompt is based on your system's hostname. That can be set in a number of ways. However DHCP can accept static hostnames from the router. So what's likely happening is your router sets your hostname to dhcp-[ip address] for each system.

Comment: Thank you, if I disconnect from internet the name changes, why is the router assigning that name, can you explain me more about this?

Comment: A router gives your computer an IP address through a protocol called Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP). Normally computers on the network have a set hostname and will announce that to others on the network. However DHCP provides an option to set the hostname of the computer instead.